# How to tell Python unittest to exit with custom code set in a function

Tags: python, batch-file, python-unittest

How do I get Python `unittest` to exit with a status code from my function?

In my `tearDown` function I have to do some processing to generate the status code, but I would like `unittest` to exit with that code. The Python script will be run from a DOS bat file and need to echo the `%ERRORLEVEL%` and I want the `%ERRORLEVEL%` to be set with `myExitCode`.

Currently, it always return `0`:

```
import logging
import unittest
import sys

myExitCode = 0

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        logging.info('Setting up test: logged stdout')

    def test(self):
        logging.info('logged more stdout')
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def tearDown(self):
        ## Mocking some processing to generate a customized exit code:
        myExitCode = 1000
        logging.info('exit code = %d', myExitCode)
        return myExitCode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('test.log', mode='a'))
    stderr_file = open('test.log', 'a')
    unittest.main(testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stderr_file), exit=False)
    logging.info('Exit Code from main: %d', myExitCode)
    sys.exit(myExitCode)
```

Batch script:

```
python myExitCode.py
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant batch file code you are using to call the python script?

Comment: I added the batch script content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a global variable here. Bear in mind this isn't very clean:

```
   def tearDown(self): 
        global myExitCode
        myExitCode = 1000
        logging.info('exit code = %d', myExitCode)
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this is working for me now. Yes, it's not cleaned but this is the system I've to work with.  Unfortunately, unittest would report as failure because I've to exit with custom exit code. :(

Comment: What is the explanation for what happened without "global"? It could be added to the answer.